# Sidekiq workers suddenly slowed down (almost like stuck workers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've been using sidekiq for a while now and it was working flawlessly (up to 5 million jobs processed). However in the past few days the workers got stuck and thus the jobs left unprocessed. Only by restarting the workers, they'll start working and consuming the jobs again, but they'll eventually stuck again (~10-30minutes, I haven't done any exact measurements).

Here's my setup:

- Rails v4.2.5.1, with ActiveJob.
- MySQL DB, clustered (with 3 masters)
- ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool set to 32 (verified in Sidekiq process as well).
- 2 sidekiq workers, 3 threads per worker (total 6).

Symptons:

- If the workers just got restarted, they process the jobs fast (~1s).
- After several jobs processed, the time needed to complete a job (the same job that previously take only ~1s to complete) suddenly spiked to ~2900s, which make the worker look like stuck.
- The slows down affect any kind of jobs (there's no specific offending job).
- CPU usage and Memory consumption is normal and no swap either.

Here is the [TTIN log](https://gist.github.com/erwinl/93d73abf6b882530d238edce9a64aaea). It seems like the process hung when:

- retrieve_connection
- clear_active_connections

But I'm not sure why it is happening. Anyone have similar experience or know something about this issue? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here's the relevant [mysql show processlist log](https://gist.github.com/erwinl/5b3d92f4deb32e993dcb877399413667).

I'm running Sidekiq on 2 different machines:

- 20.7.4.5
- 20.7.4.6

Focusing on 20.7.4.5, there were 10 connections and all of them are currently sleeping. If I understand correctly:

- 1 is passenger connection
- 3 are the currently "busy"(stuck) sidekiq workers.
- 6 are the unclosed connections.

There's no long-running query here since all the connections are currently sleeping (idle, waiting to be terminated with default timeout duration of 8 hours), is this correct?

**EDIT 2:**

So it turns out the issue has something to do with our DB configuration. We are using this schema:

`Sidekiq workers => Load balancer => DB clusters.`

With this setup, sidekiq workers start hanging after a while (completing job MUCH slower, up to 3000s, while it usually takes only 1s).

However if we setup the workers to directly talk with the DB cluster, it works flawlessly. So something is probably wrong with our setup, and this is not a sidekiq issue.

Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: 1. are you sure there is enough free memory for the workers? sidekiq workers tend to grow in memory until they use all available memory. 2. may be you are having a bottleneck in db access / connections

Comment: (1). Yes. (2). If thats the case, I should get "deadlock" exception and timeout when acquiring lock right? In this case, it seems like the process is just hung for a very long time before finally complete.

Comment: I would try to profile this by inserting timer and catching those long processes and send all available data to myself. Im quite sure the problem is not in sidekiq itself. may be there is also problem if u use t2 amazon machines which have cpu credits

Comment: Yes, I also believe this is not a sidekiq problem since it was working ok before (processed 5mil jobs w/o hiccup). TTIN logs seem to indicate a problem in DB connection, but I don't know what the problem is :(

Comment: Is there anything useful in MySQL logs? If you do a `show processlist` in mysql console (when the jobs are "stuck"), perhaps there are some long-running queries?

Comment: Hello @BoraMa, sorry for the late reply. I attached more info on the mysql processlist.